# Can I manually unzip a .war file, and then run the app that has embedded jetty?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jetty, classpath

Currently I have a spring-mvc with an embedded jetty instance, and I am using the maven war plugin that produces a 'fat' war file that I start using:

```
java -jar myfat.war
```

This makes updates to production take a long time b/c the .war file is fairly large. It would be great if I could unzip the war file, then I could just sych up whatever file has changed to my production server.

Is it possible for me to do this:

```
1. locally build my fat war file
2. locally unzip the war file
3. push to server
4. run exploded war file with embedded jetty instance
```

**If this is possible, how do I perform step#4?**  Now I don't have a .war file so I'm not sure how to start this?

I do know the main class that has my embedded server:

```
com.myapp.server.MyJettyServer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this work writing your own embedded jetty setup, no reason it couldn't work.  I'll also mention that you could use the jetty-runner artifact as well to do this.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-runner.html

Specifically down a bit on that page are examples using context.xml files.  You could easily have a context.xml file that looks to your exploded war file for startup.

Alternatively you could also put your exploded war file on your jetty instance under the webapps directory and sync that over, you don't *have* to put a .war file in there for a webapp to be deployed.